# How to return a row where a column is result of subquery and return another column which is highest of 0 or result of same subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could you please let me know how I can get the code below to work?

```
SELECT  OrderCount= (select Sum(Qty) from dbo.tblOrders WHERE OrderType in (4,6,8) ) 
-  (select Sum(Qty) from dbo.tblOrders WHERE OrderType in (2,5,10) )   ,
CASE WHEN OrderCount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE OrderCount END AS TotalOrders

FROM   dbo.tblOrders
```

Error I get in above query is

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'OrderCount'.

Comment: I'll +1 if you can make the title longer without adding any meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to a column-alias in the same scope.

You need a sub-query or a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT OrderCount = (SELECT Sum(qty) 
                        FROM   dbo.tblorders 
                        WHERE  ordertype IN ( 4, 6, 8 )) - (SELECT Sum(qty) 
                                                            FROM   dbo.tblorders 
                                                            WHERE  ordertype IN 
                                                               ( 2, 5, 10 ))
    FROM   dbo.tblorders  
)
SELECT OrderCount, 
       TotalOrders  = CASE WHEN  OrderCount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE OrderCount END 
FROM CTE
```

Comment: I think you meant refer to a column *alias* in the same scope.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Aaron!

Answer (score -1):

variables need to be `DECLARE`d like so:

```
DECLARE @OrderCount int
SELECT  @OrderCount= (select Sum(Qty) from dbo.tblOrders WHERE OrderType in (4,6,8) ) 
-  (select Sum(Qty) from dbo.tblOrders WHERE OrderType in (2,5,10) ) 
FROM   dbo.tblOrders
```

Also took the CASE out because it's not valid in a select next to an assignment